# Updating rows based on other rows in the same table

Tags: mysql

I have the following table: items

```
+----+------+-------+---------+
| id | type | color | texture |
+----+------+-------+---------+
| 1  | card | red   | rough   |
| 2  |      | red   | smooth  |
| 3  |      | red   | rough   |
| 4  |      | green | rough   |
+----+------+-------+---------+
```

I would like to update rows in the table so that if there is at least one row that has type of not NULL and the other rows also match on the other attributes, color and texture, it will add the value to the other rows. So in this example it would only add 'type' to the row id:3

Comment: Just curious, what should happen if multiple other matching rows exist with different types?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a multiple table `UPDATE` statement to do this:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

```
UPDATE items i1
JOIN items i2 
    ON i1.color = i2.color
    AND i1.texture = i2.texture
    AND i2.type IS NOT NULL
SET i1.type = i2.type
WHERE i1.type IS NULL
```